# Haskell-style recursive lazy list in Python

Tags: python, haskell

Consider a generalized Fibonacci series:

Y_n = f({Y_i}_{n-k}^{n-1})

we can implement this series in a Haskell one-liner:

```
gfib f xs = (head xs) : gfib f ((tail xs) ++ [f xs])
```

with results:

```
ghci> take 10 $ gfib sum [0, 0, 1]
[0,0,1,1,2,4,7,13,24,44]
ghci> take 10 $ gfib sum [0, 1]
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
```

I am wondering how can I implement the same series in Python with least code as possible and not using class/objects.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem, though, is that it's a *recursive* generator, which is essentially subject to the same problems as any other type of recursion. (That is, `gfib.__next__` is ultimately defined in terms of `gfib.__next__`, so you are limited by the size of the call stack just as with any other recursive function.)

Comment: Sadly I understand neither your definition (what do all those letters mean?) nor the Haskell.

Comment: Does it just need to support simple iteration (in Python the examples would use `islice`)? Or what does "lazy list" mean/support?

Comment: With my original comment, I was thinking of the self-referential definitions that define a *list* in terms of itself. This is just a straightforward recursive function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a generator:

```
def gfib(f, xs_init):
  xs = xs_init[:] # make a copy to keep all mutations local
  while True:
    x = f(xs)
    yield xs.pop(0)
    xs.append(x)
```

Comment: [version that also supports an empty list](https://tio.run/##dY2xDgIhEER7vmJKMBRebIyJf2FnLNRbdCMHF@AifD1yR22zyey8mZlLent3OM6hVhP8BE4Ukvc2gqfZhwSOlp8kxEgGL8MPaTRyVCcBfN9sCZew0KqArLHLEef1ahjZsO1fmOyI3DvS/UPSaZTeAQRKS3CwHJPsY7K0uFNKiDmwS3KLDHvd9@MyaVybGm6qMf@R1a71Bw).

Comment: Kelly's reference is also elegant

Comment: Does this have the same asymptotics as the Haskell version? Wondering if you end up wither either duplicated work or lack of sharing in memory.